# How to set column name for column n of 'x'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Hi The following query is returning: No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.

```
  public ArrayList<DocumentModel> findByDate(String code, String date, String dateFinal) throws GeneralException{
    ArrayList<DocumentModel> docs = new ArrayList<DocumentModel>();
    String d1 = date;
    String delimiter = "-";
    String[]temp = d1.split(delimiter);
    String[]temp2 = dateFinal.split("-");
    String num="";
    String alfa="";
    if (code.compareTo("")!=0){
        String[] c1 = code.split(",");
        num = c1[0];
        alfa = c1[1];
    }

    try{
        String sql = "SELECT max(issuedate),airlineOid as airlineNumericCode FROM Document  WHERE ";

        if (alfa.compareTo("")!=0) sql+=" airlineOid='"+alfa+"' and ";

        sql+=" convert(varchar,issueDate,112) >= '" + temp[0]+ temp[1] +"00'  AND convert(varchar,issueDate,112) < '"+ temp2[0]+ temp2[1] +"32' group by airlineOid";

        String sql2="select d.*,'"+num+"' as airlineNumericCode from document d,("+sql+") as t where t.airlineOid=d.airlineOid and t.issueDate=d.issueDate ORDER BY issueDate DESC ";

        ResultSet rs = this.executeQuery(sql2);
        while(rs.next()){
            docs.add((DocumentModel)this.build(rs));
        }
        if(docs != null){
            return docs;
        } else {
            return docs = null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        throw new GeneralException(ex);
    }
}
```

I cannot see where I should specify the name.
Thank you very much!
Best Regards
Ignacio

Comment: Can you run this with the Profiler running in the background and see what query actually gets executed on the SQL server side ?

Comment: No I cannot, thank you very much

Comment: @IgnacioGarat Why not? If it's because you have the Express edition of SQL Server, take a look at [AnjLab SQLProfiler](http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler). (You have got your answer already, but it may still be useful in the future.)

Comment: use `String sql = "SELECT max(issuedate) as **maxIssueDate**, airlineOid` as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem....you rename airline0id to airlineNumericCode in SQL.  Then, in sql2, you try to refer to it as airline0id.  Try this:

```
String sql = "SELECT max(issuedate) as issueDate,airlineOid as airlineNumericCode FROM Document  WHERE ";

...

String sql2="select d.*,'"+num+"' as airlineNumericCode from document d,("+sql+") as t where t.airlineNumericCode=d.airlineOid and t.issueDate=d.issueDate ORDER BY issueDate DESC ";
```

Comment: I have tried do, but now I get Invalid column name 'airlineOid'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a column alias to `max(issuedate)`, something like so:

```
String sql = "SELECT max(issuedate) as MaxIssueDate, airlineOid as airlineNumericCode FROM Document  WHERE ";
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'airlineOid'. can it be?

Comment: Sounds like the first problem was, it didn't have a name (or alias) for the first column, and the second problem--which you've now found--is that there's no column named airlineOid in table Document. But we'd have to see table structures to know for sure.